# why is my code for jquery drag and drop not working with randomised positions?

Tags: jquery

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Andy5566/FLhp6/
I am trying to make a simple card matching game where cards from Japanese and English are shuffled and the user needs to match them. I am shuffling by adding margin top and left using random numbers. This is the code for setting the playing area:

```
var questions = [["a","あ"],["i","い"],["u","う"],["e","え"],["o","お"]]
for (i=0;i<questions.length; i++)    
{var randomWidth1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 1);
var randomHeight1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 1);
var randomWidth2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 1);
var randomHeight2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 1);
$("#game").append("<span style = 'left:" + randomWidth1 + "px; top:" + randomHeight1 +     "px;'class='draggable' id ='" + questions[i][0]+ "'>" + questions[i][0] + "</span><span class='droppable' data-reading = " + questions[i][0] + ">" +  questions[i][1] + "</span>");
```

If I remove the style tag from the spans the drag and drop functionality seems to work, however that kind of defeats the purpose before the answer is right there!

Thank you for your help it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code doesn't work because you're telling the droppable to accept only if the draggable fits.

Remove the tolerance on the droppable, or make sure every item is the same width and height.

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    //tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var reading1 = ui.draggable.attr('id');
        var reading2 = $(this).data("reading");

        if (reading1 === reading2) alert("well done");
    }
});
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/FLhp6/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the style tag you just need to apply your positioning CSS a different way.

```
$("#game").append("<span class='draggable' id ='" + questions[i][0]+ "'>" + questions[i][0] + "</span><span class='droppable' data-reading = " + questions[i][0] + ">" +  questions[i][1] + "</span>").find('#'+questions[i][0]).css({'left':randomWidth1, 'top':randomHeight1});
```